# Is "should" in if-clause common in the USA?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, modal-verbs

I was wondering if the "should" in if-clause is commonly used nowadays, or if it's kinda outdated. E.g.,

> If you should meet him, tell him he owes me.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+you+meet%2Cif+you+should+meet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3). But are you suggesting a difference in meaning between forms with "should" and forms without, or do you think the meaning is identical?

Comment: Yeah, there's a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Garner's Modern American Usage* has an entry on *should* (p745) in which he gives various examples of how the word is used, including one use in a conditional sentence:

> If Bess should call, tell her I'll be back at 4 o'clock.

I infer from his inclusion of this example that Garner does not consider the usage outdated.

Swan, in *Practical English Usage* (p237), states in Section 261(1) *if...should* :

> We can suggest that something is unlikely, or not particularly
> probable, by using *should*...in the *if*-clause:
>
> - If you should run into Peter, tell him he owes me a letter.

So, while *If you should meet him, tell him he owes me* is not as common as *If you meet him, tell him he owes me*, it is not outdated. It is a useful alternative when the speaker thinks there is less likelihood that the meeting will happen.

Comment: Thank you a lot!